# How can I program automatic gain control in C# ?

Tags: c#, camera

I drive Basler camera with a C# program and I would like to perform an automatic gain control for gain is automatically adjusted according to the brightness.
I need your help because at first glance, I did not realize how well visualized it.

I thought to test the brightness of the image (pixel brightness) and if it is not the maximum we can therefore increment the gain. I would like therefore to this little program that would allow the automatic gain control of my camera. Is this the right approach? Or is it that you advise me rather something else?

A library is supplied with the camera and thanks to her I control the camera. The user has the opportunity to capture a photo, video capture and stop video capture. It can also control the gain manually. I wish now program the automatic gain, that is to say, the gain is automatically adjusted depending on the intensity of the captured image. Users just activate this setting and the gain setting would automatically.

I thank you in advance,

Sebbur

Comment: At the moment I have no code to automatic gain control because I don't know how to do that. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: With the documentation, I made this code :


 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.GainSelector].SetValue(PLUsbCamera.GainSelector.DigitalAll);
                camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.AutoGainLowerLimit].SetValue(0.0);  camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.AutoTargetBrightness].SetValue(0.50196);                camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.GainAuto].SetValue(PLUsbCamera.GainAuto.Continuous); 
        }

Comment: But now, I have an error : " Parameter in path CameraDevice can only be accessed when the camera is open. "
Any ideas ?